# Abstract class as output

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

if I have a method in an abstract class:

```
public virtual DoSomething(out MyBase base1){}
```

but in my derived class I need to use the method from a class derived from MyBase I would need something like:

```
public override DoSomething(out MyBaseCustom base1){}
```

What is the correct approach to get this functionality?

Comment: Do you need to use implementation only of base class?

Comment: Do you encounter any error?

Comment: @LeiYang, yes, the error is that the override can't find an appropriate method in the base class since the parameter is a different class.

Comment: @kat1330 Yes, I need to use both in conjunction. I can really only edit the class MyBase though and the derived class that holds DoSomething

Answer (score 0):

#### I was confronted with this problem once. This is how I solved it:

**Step 1** Make the base class generic

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(out T c)
    {
        // somehow assign c of course
    }
}
```

**Step 2** When deriving from the base class do it like this

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    public override void DoSomething(out DerivedClass c)
    {
        // somehow assign c of course
    }
}
```

not super elegant, but does the job

### EDIT

#### Respectively, when making use of abstract methods

**Step 1** Make the base class generic

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(out T c);
}
```

and

**Step 2** When deriving from the base class do it like this

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    public override void DoSomething(out DerivedClass c)
    {
        // somehow assign c of course
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Comparing this with Corith Malin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would try and make the out parameter an interface.  Which would give you resulting code like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(out IMyObject obj)
    {
        obj = new MyObject();
    }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyClass
{
    public override void DoSomething(out IMyObject obj)
    {
        obj = new MyChildObject();
    }

}

public interface IMyObject
{
}

public class MyObject : IMyObject
{
}

public class MyChildObject : MyObject
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Comparing this with Benj's suggestion.